# Rest Assured Proxy Setting issue (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out exception)

Tags: java, proxy, testng, rest-assured

One of the API (Say XYZ API) call alone requires the proxy to be set, When I run a suite where this API is called before and after every test script in the suite there is **`java.net.ConnectException`** seen randomly.

Only for XYZ API, I set and reset the proxy using the line:

```
RestAssured.proxy(String, int)
```

and

```
RestAssured.reset()
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Could this be a bug?

**Note**: This API call fails randomly just saying first 10 times it would have passed may be the 11th it fails with exception rest all scripts are then skipped in execution.

Code snapshot:

```
public void GetAuthenticationToken(String userid, String password) 
{           
    RestAssured.proxy(config.getProperty("ProxyHost"),Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("ProxyPort"))); //Authentication API is outside network and requires proxy

    String APIUrl_Aut = config.getProperty("APIUrl_Aut");
    String APIBody_Aut = "grant_type=password&username="+userid+"&password="+password;

    //Making post request with authentication
    Response response = RestAssured.given().log().all().headers("Accept", "application/json","Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded").body(APIBody_Aut).
            when().post(APIUrl_Aut).then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().response();

    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200)
    {
        WritePropertyToTemp("AUTH_TOKEN", "Bearer "+response.body().jsonPath().get("access_token").toString());
        WritePropertyToTemp("AUTH_TOKEN_OnlyToken",response.body().jsonPath().get("access_token").toString());
        log.info("Authentication token generated successfully");
    }
    else
        log.info("Authentication token failed to generate");
    RestAssured.reset(); //Resetting proxy

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to check your requests with wireshark? May be you configure RestAssured somewhere else?